# Using Chocolately how do I upgrade just one side-by-side package version?

Tags: chocolatey

I have to support two versions of the .net core SDK owing to compatibility issues.

Therefore I run:

```
choco install dotnetcore-sdk --version 2.1.700 -y --side-by-side
choco install dotnetcore-sdk --version 3.1.100 -y --side-by-side
```

Now, if I want to take `2.1.700` to `2.2.402` but leave `3.1.100` as-is how do I do that without uninstalling all versions and reinstalling 2.2.402 and 3.1.100 side by side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oh turns out you can just do:

```
choco uninstall dotnetcore-sdk --version 2.1.700 -y --side-by-side
choco install dotnetcore-sdk --version 2.2.402 -y --side-by-side
choco install dotnetcore-sdk --version 3.1.100 -y --side-by-side
```